# Shopware Product API response with "Cannot unset string offsets"

Tags: api, request, response, shopware

After some testing with the Product API of Shopware 6 I get a 500 error that says "Cannot unset string of offsets".
That information isnt enought for me, to debug it, sicne iam kinda new to Shopware 6 APIs.
This is the error:

```
{
    "errors": [{
        "code": "0",
        "status": "500",
        "title": "Internal Server Error",
        "detail": "Cannot unset string offsets"
    }]
}
```

Iam using this site: https://reqbin.com/ 
And I call the URL: https://www.my-url.de/api/product via POST Request. 
As authorization i use a bearer token i grab from the getToken GET-Request. 
My Request-Content looks like the following:

```
{
    "productId":"fd1be1ea-884a-4049-b143-605d8dfaa589",
    "parentId":"fd1be1ea-884a-4049-b143-605d8dfaa589",
    "name":"Sorelie",
    "taxId":"f68a9c3c-8686-4c2e-a759-7062fc457cf7",
    "productNumber":"16345583549",
    "minPurchase":"1",
    "purchasePrice":"0",
    "price":{
        "currencyId":"b7d2554b-0ce8-47cd-82f3-ac9bd1c0dfca",
        "net":"0",
        "gross":"0"
    },
    "stock":"0",
    "images":"",
    "atributes":"",
    "categoryId":"29"
}
```

I copy paste the taxId and currencyId from a existing database and just format it the same as the productId and parentId i generate manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have 2 problems:

1. price fields should be an array of objects e.g.

```
    "price":[{
        "currencyId":"b7d2554b-0ce8-47cd-82f3-ac9bd1c0dfca",
        "net":"0",
        "gross":"0"
    }],
```

2. You need to remove dashes from all id fields e.g.
   fd1be1ea-884a-4049-b143-605d8dfaa589  => fd1be1ea884a4049b143605d8dfaa589

Comment: The Dashes were the problem, thanks a lot^^